# How to compare and rank ETF's in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, algorithmic-trading, trading

hope you are well?

So I have recently started trying to experiment with trading algorithms. I am trying to create an ETF rotation strategy.
I am struggling with how to compare the returns between the etfs? (Error at the bottom) Am I making a simple mistake? Can you give me any pointers on what I need to do in order to rank them as I don't particularly want to write hundreds of if statements, is there any shortcut?

Thanks for any advice!
(This isn't the complete code)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr


yf.pdr_override()
now = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
emasUsed = [60] 
etfs = ['FDN','IBB','IEZ','IGV','IHE','IHF','IHI','ITA','ITB','IYJ','IYT','IYW','IYZ'
        ,'KBE','KCE','KIE','PBJ','PBS','SMH','VNQ','XLB','XLP','XLU','XOP','XRT']
monthly_return = []
top_etfs = [None,None,None,None,None,None]
total = 0

##for etf in etfs:
##    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(etf, start, now)
##    monthly_returns = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()      
##    #print("ETF: ",etf," Monthly Returns: ",monthly_returns)
##    monthly_return.append(str(monthly_returns))
##    for i in range(30):
##        daily_returns = df['Adj Close'].resample('D').ffill().pct_change()
##        cumulative_returns = (daily_returns + 1).comprod()
##        print(cumulative_returns)
        

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(etfs, start, now)
daily_return = (df['Adj Close'].pct_change())
monthly_return = (df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change())
print(monthly_return)
print(daily_return)

for i in df.index:
    print(daily_return['FDN'])
    if daily_return['FDN'] > daily_return['IBB']:
        print("FDN is better than IBB")
    else:
        print("IBB is better than FDN")
```

if daily_return['FDN'] > daily_return['IBB']:
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1479, in **nonzero**
f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Your question isn't "how to compare and rank ETFs in Python", it's "how to deduce the truth value of a series in python". **Reading** the error that's being thrown is an essential step in programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: What is an ouput of print(daily_return['FDN'])?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg , the output should be something like "2018-1-1    0.012345"

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you trying to numerically compare series themselves instead of  series members. Note also that the very first data point is [2018-01-01 00:00:00 NaN]

So in your code it should be

```
for i in df.index[1:]:
    if daily_return['FDN'][i] > daily_return['IBB'][i]:
       ...
```